# Access Azure Blob Storage only logged in user

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have application in asp.net and uploaded to Azure App service. I have file upload on the azure blob. Here issue is my blob is accessible to public I want to access images and docs in the blobs only accessible when my application is logged in. If I log out then those should not be access. How can I achieve this using azure blob storage?

Comment: Have you tried making the container private?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS yes if container blob private then I could not see the images which is loading from the storage blob.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can configure the web app with Azure AD auth(Easy Auth), follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad).

After doing the steps in the doc above, it will create an AD App in your AAD tenant. Navigate to the AD App in the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `API permissions`, add the delegated permission of `Azure Storage`.

[image]

Then navigate to the `authsettings` of the web app in the [resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com/), add `["resource=https://storage.azure.com"]` to the `additionalLoginParams`, details see this [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-app-service/azure-app-service-easyauth-and-azure-active-directory-flows/ba-p/1099890).

[image]

Navigate to the storage account in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> make sure the user account has a role e.g. `Storage Blob Data Contributor`, if not, add it for the user, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

After doing the steps above, use the user account to login  the web app, you can get the access token with `https://webappname.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me`, then you can use the token to call the [Storage REST API - GET Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) to access the things in the storage container.

Comment: I have my own forms authentication used. Will this solution work with that?

Comment: @TusharMaru Basically yes, the easy auth is above code.